# nspopupbutton not behaving properly - showing Reversely

Tags: macos, nstableview, xamarin.mac, nspopupbutton, macos-high-sierra

I am facing unique issue with nspopupbutton in one of my mac application.
I am using table view to load the filters, filters having different options, We can select the option from dropdown. As like I shown below.
[image]

My Issue is , After adding another filter (table view cell), My first cell dropdown text showing reversely. Please find the screenshot below.
[image]

Please share your thoughts , I really trapped in this issue.
**Issue only in High Sierra MacOS.**

Edit
I am creating custom cell in XIB as like below and binding the NS elements using tag
[image]

Code I used to load table view

```
public override nint GetRowCount (NSTableView tableView)
            {
                return appliedFilters.Count;
            }


public override NSView GetViewForItem (NSTableView tableView, NSTableColumn tableColumn, nint row)
            {

var vw = (FiltersCell)tableView.MakeView (parentVC.appliedFilters.ElementAt((int)row), this);
 // Binddata is method I used to bind data in FIlterCell   
 vw.BindData (parentVC.appliedFilters [(int)row].ToString(), (int)row,parentVC);
 return vw;
 }

public override nfloat GetRowHeight (NSTableView tableView, nint row)
{

    return 30;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code you could add to the question? Did you flip any views? Why are the popup buttons inactive and the window active?

Comment: @Willeke: I updated my question with few more details.  Let me know this information is useful for you .

Comment: Does `FiltersCell` do anything to the views? Did you add constraints in the rows?

Comment: @Willeke : The issue is fixed by adding wantLayer = true in parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macOS HS changes a number of layer based things, and if we are using the "old" NSCells somewhere it wouldn't surprise me they broke something.

You could try setting your parent view to layer based (WantsLayer = true or in IB) and see if that "fixes" things.

Multiple people have hit layer based regressions / issues in HS (not bugs in Xamarin.Mac).

**From xamarin team**